# Determine overlapping lines (to remove them)?

Tags: algorithm, svg, dxf

I'm looking for a way to remove overlapping lines from a 2D image (i.e. SVG, or 2D DXF). I can code but I'm not sure I know what kind of algorithm would be best suited for this sort of work.

The use case here is, sometimes when generating an SVG for example from another data source you end up with "duplicate" lines, i.e. lines that literally trace the same path in the image. Visually this isn't a problem when rendered (other than the extra bloat in the file), but it is a problem when using a laser cutter which interprets these line segments as paths to cut with the laser and you don't want it going over the same path twice.

Can anyone walk me through what that algorithm might look like? I'm having a difficult time visualizing it.

Comment: A generic line-line intersection algoritm: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/panos/cg13/l03.pdf I think you can get inspiration for overlapping case.

Comment: This could get very complex. You should elaborate on the set of base elements you are handling: Are there only (straight) lines, or the full range of path segments: lines, quadratic/cubic beziers, arcs? Could there be grafic primitives to account for like ellipses, rectangles, or polygons? How do you define "overlap"? Are there edge conditions, for example if a cubic bezier approximates a circle segment? What should happen if lines track the same path only part of the way, because they have different start/end points, but coincide inbetween?

Comment: I think the idea here would be that the definition of "overlap" should be configurable. For example, +/- 0.01mm.

Ideally, I'd like to see the full set of base elements handled and have this work for an arbitrary SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what should happen when you find that path segments overlap only for part of their extent. So here is something I could do in the Inkscape GUI. Maybe that could serve as a template for a doable algorithm:

1. Convert all grafical primitives to paths.
2. Disassemble all paths so that each individual segments is a separate path.
3. Give all of these  paths a stroke width that is double the "overlap" threshold.
4. Convert the contours of the strokes to paths.
5. For all pairs of paths, cut out the intersection. (Beware: with Inkscape, that is a destructive process, so make copies.)
6. Measure the size (viewBox) of the resulting intersection pieces. If its length is above a "length" threshold, the segments could be said to overlap.

For Point 1, I can't name a library, but same as Point 4 it is what every vector renderer essentially does, so that should be achievable with existing resources. Point 2 and 3 are trivial. For Point 5 there are [existing libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-intersections) to determine intersection points. Point 6 could then simply be solved by determining the greatest distance between intersection points on one pair of path objects.